# Cannot infer type when have nested generic and a using define

Tags: c#, generics, using

Consider the following example, where we have a list whose generic parameter is a Tuple with a type that is defined in a `using` statement at the top.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using MyCustomName = String;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Tuple<MyCustomName>> someList = new List<Tuple<MyCustomName>>();
            MyCustomName someString = "Hello world";
            someList.Add(new Tuple<MyCustomName>(someString));
        }
    }
}
```

The `Add` causes the following compiler error:

```
The type arguments for method 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Tuple<String>>.Add(System.Tuple<String>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

This error is at least misleading in one regard, you cannot explicitly specify the type arguments on Add since it is not itself a generic method.

However, given that, to my understanding, the `using` statement is not really doing anything much more sophisticated than find and replace, I do not see why the compiler cannot handle this. Why is this error happening and is there any way around other (other than obviously ditching the `using`).

Also, meta-question: what is the correct tag for type deceleration `using`?

Comment: For your meta question: I'd use `using-directives` to clarify that it's not a `using` *statement*. But then you'd need to be aware of the difference beforehand, of course ;) (A `using` statement is the one that disposes of a resource. A `using` directive is the one that imports a namespace or aliases a type.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, this line causes the first problem:

```
using MyCustomName = String;
```

This one works:

```
using MyCustomName = System.String;
```

Comment: That's weird, that has fixed mine, but that wasn't the line that was erroring

Comment: @T.Kiley: I got the same results as AlexD. Can you edit your post to show the *complete* code you're using? (You don't currently have a `using` directive for `System` or `System.Collections.Generics` for example. Also, are you using Visual Studio, and if so, which version?

Comment: @JonSkeet did not think they would be significant! Updated the code, this is in VS2010 (Pro). Actually compiling it revealed the correct error, it was only the continuous compilation that was not pointing it out. Also, disabling Visual Assist seemed to reveal the error in continuous compilation.

Comment: @T.Kiley: That's fine, as most of the time they wouldn't be (although it does make it easier to reproduce something if it's a copy/paste/compile with no changes). Glad to hear that a full recompile gave a more sensible result.

Comment: @JonSkeet I could reproduce the issue several times, but not in a stable way. My steps: (1) take the sample code, but `//using MyCustomName = String;`, compile -> several errors, including the reported one; (2) quickly remove the comment, do _not_ compile -> only the reported error left.

Comment: @AlexD: Interesting. No wonder I couldn't see it when compiling it from the console, of course :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty much OK to me (Visual Studio 2012 Pro Update 4)

[image: notfound]